# Calling a procedure for a fetch of a cursor

Tags: oracle, cursor, procedure

Do not know if it's possible, but must create a procedure that, during the fetch of a query, browse data in another procedure.

Example:

Below is another example of how real is my structure:

```
TYPE T_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;

PROCEDURE PR_ACCOUNT_ACTIVE(CCURSOR OUT T_CURSOR) IS

    CURSOR CURSOR_ACCOUNT IS
        SELECT ID_ACCOUNT, NAME, 0 AS SUM_BALANCE 
          FROM ACCOUNT
         WHERE STATUS = 'A'
         ORDER BY DATE_CREATE DESC;

    REG_ACCOUNT CURSOR_ACCOUNT%ROWTYPE;

    BEGIN

        OPEN CURSOR_ACCOUNT;
        LOOP

            FETCH CURSOR_ACCOUNT INTO REG_ACCOUNT;
            EXIT WHEN CURSOR_ACCOUNT%NOTFOUND;

            /*** 
            At this point I need to call the procedure PR_ACCOUNT_BALANCE (below) and
            her return and use (field SUM_VAL_MONEY) to update the field SUM_BALANCE
            this current cursor (CURSOR_ACCOUNT) and then return to the cursor CCURSOR
            ***/

        END LOOP;
        CLOSE CURSOR_ACCOUNT;

    END;

END PR_ACCOUNT_ACTIVE;


PROCEDURE PR_ACCOUNT_BALANCE(P_ID_ACCOUNT IS NUMBER, CCURSOR OUT T_CURSOR) IS

  BEGIN

    OPEN CCURSOR FOR

      SELECT ID_ACCOUNT
       , SUM(VAL_MONEY) AS SUM_VAL_MONEY
        FROM ACCOUNT_CONTRIBUTION
       WHERE ID_ACCOUNT = P_ID_ACCOUNT
       GROUP BY ID_ACCOUNT

END PR_ACCOUNT_BALANCE;
```

My big question is that in both procedures, the return is always performed by a cursor, and I can not change that.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the problem you're trying to solve.  What does it mean to "browse data in another procedure"?  In `PROC_1`, there is a `FETCH` but you're not fetching into anything.  Is `c1` after the `FETCH` supposed to be a record rather than a cursor?  And what do you want to assign to `field1` of the `c1` record?

Comment: @rafael:First of all ,do you want to use  the value `c1.field1`   `fetch from the first cursor` in `proc_1` to be input of `Proc_2` and then return `cursor ` from the proc_2? and do some manipulation inside `proc_1`? If yes this is possible .

Comment: @GauravSoni I changed the example of my question to get a better understanding. But his assertion is correct, that's what I gotta do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PROCEDURE PR_ACCOUNT_ACTIVE(CCURSOR OUT T_CURSOR) IS

CURSOR CURSOR_ACCOUNT IS
    SELECT ID_ACCOUNT, NAME, 0 AS SUM_BALANCE 
      FROM ACCOUNT
     WHERE STATUS = 'A'
     ORDER BY DATE_CREATE DESC;

REG_ACCOUNT CURSOR_ACCOUNT%ROWTYPE;

--create a record to fetch the value of the cursor 
TYPE p_rec is RECORD
(
  ID_ACCOUNT ACCOUNT.ID_ACCOUNT%TYPE
 ,SUM_VAL    PLS_INTEGER
);

 v_rec p_rec; --variable of that record

BEGIN

    OPEN CURSOR_ACCOUNT;
    LOOP

        FETCH CURSOR_ACCOUNT INTO REG_ACCOUNT;
        EXIT WHEN CURSOR_ACCOUNT%NOTFOUND;
           PR_ACCOUNT_BALANCE(REG_ACCOUNT.ID_ACCOUNT,v_cursor);
             FETCH  v_cursor INTO v_rec;
               UPDATE ACCOUNT SET sum_balance=v_rec.sum_val 
                    WHERE id_account=v_rec.id_account --assuming id_account is primary key of accounts table  
             CLOSE v_cursor;  

     END LOOP;
     CLOSE CURSOR_ACCOUNT;

END;

END PR_ACCOUNT_ACTIVE;

 PROCEDURE PR_ACCOUNT_BALANCE(P_ID_ACCOUNT IS NUMBER, CCURSOR OUT T_CURSOR) IS

 BEGIN

  OPEN CCURSOR FOR

  SELECT ID_ACCOUNT
   , SUM(VAL_MONEY) AS SUM_VAL_MONEY
    FROM ACCOUNT_CONTRIBUTION
   WHERE ID_ACCOUNT = P_ID_ACCOUNT
   GROUP BY ID_ACCOUNT

END PR_ACCOUNT_BALANCE;
```

> I have not compile the code ,but i think this will give you an idea of the approach.

**Suggestion**

1. If you are using Oracle11g ,then use `automatic subprogramming inline` feature to optimize this procedure call.[link](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/PlsqlNewFeaturesAndEnhancements_11gR1.php#automatic_subprogram_inlining)
2. you can use `update clause` in cursor and `where current of` while updating

Comment: @RafaeldePaula:Please try this piece of code ,and if  you face any issue ,tell me the with the error logs .thanks

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to use this code and then say if it worked or not.

Comment: Gaurav, Using the above structure as you went, it worked perfectly. However, what I want to do is not an update on ACCOUNT, but assign the return value of the field SUM_BALANCE CURSOR_ACCOUNT and then return it to the CCURSOR the first procedure (which is an output cursor). It has to do this, or have to work with temporary table?

Comment: @RafaeldePaula:Yaa fetch all the records into temporary table and then return the open `ccursor` and return that cursor .